# Is this behaviour adequate? Shouldn't edits add content?

Tags: discussion, editing, reputation, suggested-edits, users

Hi fellows,

I don't want to point fingers in here, but there is a user that has **all** his reputation from removing "thanks" and "hi". Except for a single answer with one upvote. I know (I read the post on meta Stack Overflow) you don't like greetings, but that's not what I'm talking about.

He adds no other information as far as I've seen, in all edits simply removing greetings. This is not even reputation farming, it's worse, and, in my opinion, a repulsive behaviour that should not be taken so normally.

I do not blame him only, however; I blame those which approve such edits: why? Why on Earth would you do that so often? That is more close to censorship, and is certainly not added value.

Comment: One can only earn a relatively small amount of reputation from edits. And it doesn't really seem all that awful, even if it would be nicer if edits were more substantial. But it seems to make you _really_ upset, with some really strong words like "repulsive" and "enraging". Maybe... Relax a little bit?

Comment: @mattdm, well... I already dislike removing greetings even if something else is added (in fact I made [a question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186173/why-cant-i-greet-you)). But I guess you're right, it did come out a little stronger than I intended to...

Comment: @JMCF125 - I for one hate greetings and like them removed. This isn't a forum. Say hi in the chatroom.

Comment: @slm, well I'm not forcing you to greet me, am I? Nor should I. Still, you do force me to do the opposite. Am I suppose to believe that's OK?

Comment: @JMCF125 - wow, you're killing me. As the OP it's your prerogative to role back an edit that takes your precious greetings out. But someone else will likely remove them down the road too, so I think you're in the minority here, and the last time I checked the SE site's don't have a House of Representatives and a Congress to make sure the smaller states have equal representation. Sorry it's just one of those things that's best to let go.

Comment: @slm, sorry, I don't mean to be annoying, I already let it go.

Comment: @JMCF125 - you're not annoying, just persistent. 8-). Let's work on the trap Q instead. Think 1/2 full in times like these! BTW, notice I didn't remove your "Hi Fellows".

Comment: @slm, thanks. That would be too ironic. `:)`

Comment: For anyone coming across this Q&A. Background reading is likely needed: read this Wikipedia article about [High- and low-context cultures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_context_culture) as well as this Area51 Q&A: [Are Stack Overflow (in language x) proposals actually viable?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/are-stack-overflow-in-language-x-proposals-actually-viable#answer-5233).

Comment: @slm This has nothing to do with high- and low-context cultures. High/low-context cultures are about **routine communication**. Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum, it is a knowledge repository. One would no more use greetings in a Stack Exchange question or answer than in an encyclopedia article.

Comment: @Gilles - The OP referenced those links in the comments below, I was simply moving them up here. I wasn't agreeing w/ it, only moving his links so that if anyone were to come across this Q they would be more informed as to what the OP was talking about. As I stated in my A, greetings and such have no business on the site, and I have no isues with someone removing them from Q&A's and getting 2 points for it.

Comment: @Gilles, I know in Wikipedia discussions, however; the behaviour is more friendly and open-minded. And as us, they're trying to expand knowledge. High/low-context culture differentiation does come into subject here.

Comment: @JMCF125 yes, but you never see "hi guys" in a Wikipedia _article_. that's the comparison that's being made here.

Comment: @strugee, that is beacause in Wikipedia, the discussion and the article are separated, while here, the question and comments are together.

Comment: @JMCF125 right. but the point is that comments = discussion and questions/answers = article.

Comment: @strugee, indeed. However, I disagree with that point. For example, in questions and answers, one often sees "Edit: as some_user pointed out, (...)". That isn't found on Wikipedia articles, and while a comparison between Stack Exchange and Wikipedia can be made, it shouldn't be so direct IMHO.

Comment: @JMCF125 direct or no, the analogy works. the culture of Stack Exchange dictates that answers are more like Wikipedia articles than discussions.

Comment: @strugee, my point is that it only *partially* works. I still think we should be more friendly. Prohibiting a normal nice human behaviour cannot be ever good.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know exactly who you're talking about (and I have an idea who) but removing those items is perfectly fine, IMO. So what if he get's 2 points in this manner per edit, as soon as he gets to 2K that incentive goes away and if he continues then he's providing a service, which may be viewed as low value, but non the less it's providing the site with "some" value.

I've likely approved his edits and will continue to do so, to me it's a value, though in your opinion small. I truly wouldn't worry about it.

At the end of the day how does it impact your interactions with the site?

Comment: Value!? It's more like censorship!

Comment: @JMCF125 - are you joking? How does it even effect you? So should we lock him up in prison for breaking the SE law? Let it go, find a Q that needs answering and focus on that, this is a waste of your energy and enthusiasm.

Comment: Come on! It's not value, for god's sake! I'm just trying to make a point. And I'd answer a question if I could, but either I don't know, or it already answered way better than anything I'd write.

Comment: @JMCF125 - Everyone is entitled to their opinion. Well we could let it go and work on your Q instead. There are many ways to participate on the site, answering is one. Asking Q's is another. So would you prosecute every jaywalker too? 8-). Maybe he can't answer Q's either and this is his way of "participating"? 8-). Let's let it go, bigger fish to fry my friend.

Comment: And he can't ask as well? I have trouble believing that. What kind of contribution is his?

Comment: @JMCF125 - he's not grinding me with this Q! 8-). What other technology Q's do you have, load up the site with them, I'd love to help you with that stuff.

Comment: Alright, I always try to make good questions, not simply questions that solve my problem.

Answer (score 7):

I think your reaction is both disproportionate (it certainly doesn't warrant the sort of emotive language you used: it's the Internet, it's not personal), and misguided.

The user (whoever they are) deserves the reputation for their contribution. In all communities, there are a wide range of roles where people can *volunteer* their time, commensurate with their ability and interest. Making small, **valid** edits is one way to incrementally increase the value and utility of the site. It should be rewarded, and it is.

They may not have the technical skills of some of the >50k members, nor as much time to donate as others, but they are trying to improve the site, and doubtless their own knowledge of Unix & Linux at the same time.

Rather than rush to judgement, why don't you just accept that the strength of this site and the community it fosters is dependent upon a diverse group of people, skills and enthusiasms and that disparaging any one of those paints you in a far less flattering light than it does them.

Comment: My reaction has nothing wrong. And what «emotive language»? «The user (whoever they are) deserves the reputation for their contribution.» - no, he doesn't. The system is wrong, my point. «Rather than rush to judgement, (...)» - that whole paragraph is just wrong. Who said I didn't accept «that the strength of this site and the community it fosters is dependent upon a diverse group of people»? I'm saying the behaviour is not only not an example of of that, as a counter-example. Removing greetings is not a skill.

Comment: @JMCF125 - removing greetings takes "some" skill and this is to Jason's point. There are many roles to play on a team. Is the kicker on an (American) football team not part of the team b/c they only marginally effect the outcome of the game? Also realize that the internet has many communities and they all work in slightly different ways. This is how the SE sites work (like it or hate it) perhaps if it's that annoying to you then perhaps the SE sites isn't the best place for you to spend your time? I'd hate to see anyone leave but this becomes unproductive after a time.

Comment: @slm, sorry, I don't really get that reference. Just to add that this is not how SE sites work: it's how low-context cultures work (there's an answer on Area51 mentioning it, but I can't find it now). The point is, in other languages, it would be (and is) different.

Comment: @JMCF125 - what do languages have to do with it? I just read your profile and now understand you better. All I can offer you is advice. Coexisting with others is the most productive way to live. Is it easy? No, compromising never is, but I wouldn't be too high brow about myself either. Every day ppl ask questions on this site and me with a rank of almost 40K learns many new things that I did not know before. These questions push me to gain new insights and new understandings on things that I didn't know before. All b/c ppl ask Q's and I'm willing to research and educate myself on these things.

Comment: @slm, I'll try to find that answer on Area51, and you'll get it.

Comment: @JMCF125 - (continued form above) - that is the proposition that is offered to you to participate in a constructive manner on this site vs. not. You'll do as you wish as boundless others have before and after you, but fixating on this one single thing is wasteful of your obvious energies and enthusiasm. Why not post Q's about how you made your SVG flag and then provide the answer showing how? That is the different path I'm trying to help you see.

Comment: @slm, found [it](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/are-stack-overflow-in-language-x-proposals-actually-viable#answer-5233)! (you should also read the question though) And alright, as I said, I have already let it go; it just seemed something I just note you at the time. To do the SVG flag, I simply opened Notepad++ (back when I used Windows) and started writing according to the W3C spec, making the calculations to know where the points of the star should be on paper. I doubt anyone interested would find that hard to do (ad I wouldn't know where to post it).

Comment: @JMCF125 - see if you can adapt the flag into an actual Q, you can then answer your own Q. Was there any repetitive tasks which could be loops or is there something dynamic about it? perhaps you could write a templated solution that could read a high level description of the flag and create some/all of the flags of the world?

Comment: @slm, interesting, but I don't have such time. I'll considered that on Summer holidays.

Comment: @JMCF125 - here's my thoughts on the Area51 Q you posted: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/are-stack-overflow-in-language-x-proposals-actually-viable/12289#12289

Comment: @JMCF125 - the flag idea could be extremely useful as a general purpose library of world flags that could be programmatically maintained anytime someone wanted a version of a flag with XvsY dimensions. It could be generated dynamically as needed. It would be easier to maintain than a static library of images too.