# My question wasn't specific enough, but got I got the right answer anyway. How should I proceed?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, duplicate

I have a question about my Unix & Linux Stack Exchange post: [Interpret variables from read in string with shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521174/interpret-variables-from-read-in-string-with-shell-script)

The question how I asked it (I tried to break it down to the relevant point) didn't mentioned that in my input-text-file are shell-Commands. But one of the answers mentioned this may be a problem and already gave a working solution to this problem.
How do i proceed with my question? I can edit and clarify my question, but do I mention that I clarified it? 
And because my original question wasn't specific enough, one answer I got also includes a non relevant part (but it also contains the working solution). How do i proceed with this? Leave a comment that the original poster edits his/her answer suitable for my clarified question?

Third but minor point: As I understood this, one does not say thanks here (instead vote etc.). This is kind of strange to ask a question and don't end it with any complimentary close. So the question just has to end with the "questionmark"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked duplicates and the existing answers addressed the question that you wrote. That'd be enough, in my opinion, to open a separate question. If there was confusion amongst the commenters or answerers about what you wanted, then I would recommend editing your original question. Above and beyond the existing answers, you've also accepted one of them, which implies that you consider your problem solved.

As-is, it sounds like you have a new, separate question. Because it's similar to your previous question, I would make it clear how it's different, perhaps even linking to your previous question. That way, people don't accidentally suggest the existing questions as duplicates again.

On your third point, "thanks" are generally considered extraneous in Stack Exchange posts. There's been [some discussion here on Meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5332/editing-other-peoples-posts-to-remove-thanks) about the issue and [when not to do such edits](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5319/editing-questions-recently-put-on-hold-dont-do-trivial-edits). My recommendation would be to keep the post focused on the technical aspects; the point of this site is to gather Questions and Answers; I take the assumption that if you got a good Answer, you appreciate it: by accepting it and possibly voting it up.

Comment: Okay, yes, my problem is perfectly solved by an answer given to my question, but not by the answers given in the duplicates.
So I added "Additional Information" to my question und added a comment to the right answer where i pointed out, which part solved my problem.
Is that approach acceptable?

Comment: I think that's a reasonable solution, yes. If you had NOT gotten an acceptable answer, and then your question was closed against incorrect duplicates, the right thing would be to edit your question and get it reopened. Of course, even better than that is to do your best to write up a question that includes anything that you think might be important to your situation. It's easier said than done :)